# Can not run Kundera with spring and tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, kundera

I'm trying to get Kundera up and running in combination with Spring and Tomcat 7 but i get the following error after adding the Kundera dependencies to my pom file.

Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.uni.masterThesis</groupId>
<artifactId>bmsapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>3.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bmsapp Maven Webapp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <spring-data-neo4j.version>${project.version}</spring-data-neo4j.version>
    <neo4j.version>2.0.1</neo4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
</properties>

   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus</id>
        <name>Kundera Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
    <id>kundera-missing</id>
    <name>Kundera Public Missing Resources Repository</name>
    <url>http://kundera.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/maven-missing-resources</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>bmsapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate implementation of the JSR-303 Bean Validation Spec API. 
        (SDN makes use of the javax.validation:validation-api dependency and hibernate 
        provides a concrete implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed  to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/bmsapp]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/bmsapp]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
   Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1189)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

When i leave out the Kundera dependecy everything works fine. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! This solved the problem for me:

[Make Tomcat Ignore Servlet in WEB-INF/LIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338102/make-tomcat-ignore-servlet-in-web-inf-lib)

I changed the Kundera dependecy to:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
             </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
```